# Authenticating Dropwizard rest APIs using facebook authentication token for android app

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, openid, dropwizard

I have following technology stack for an android app.

1. Facebook login on android app
2. Retrofit Rest client - for executing rest API on android
3. Dropwizard Rest server - Rest API server

How can I authenticate my rest APIs using facebook authentication token received after facebook login.

Also there could I use OpenId and how?

Comment: What exactly are you asking here? What have you done so far? Is it the rest part that causes you issues?The facebook auth part?

Comment: As pandaadb said, please specify your question. If you just want to ask how to authenticate and authorize requests in DW (OpenId will also work), then please read DW documentation --> http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.1/docs/manual/auth.html